# Getting a Data Abort error when attempting to save used register and return address on stack in ARM based assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

[instruction run before error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD5V7.png) [data abort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EQ41.png) [next instruction goes to invalid instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prCmt.png)

The image is taken from the debugger mode in CCS.

The problem statement for this assignment is:

1. In your first version program you calculate the rounded average of the 16 Celsius temperature values and put the result in a named memory location called Celsius_Av.
2. When the average version is working correctly, you develop and call a procedure that determines the Fahrenheit value for each of Celsius values and puts the Fahrenheit values in an array called FahrenheitTemps. The procedure also calculates the average Fahrenheit temperature and returns this average to the mainline that will put it in a memory location called Fahrenheit_Av.

I was able to do the first section fine and am attempting the second part. Here is my code, I can't seem to get past the data abort when I save used register and return on stack.

```
   .text
   .global _start
    _start:
    .equ    NUM, 8


                    LDR     R13,=STACK              @   Point at stack pointer to bottom of stack space
                    ADD     R13,R13,#0x100          @   Point stack pointer at top of stack
                    LDR     R0,=FAHRENHEIT_TEMPS    @   Load pointer to second array
                    LDR     R1,=FAHRENHEIT_AV       @   Load pointer to second array
                    MOV     R2,#NUM
                    STMFD   R13!,{R0-R2}            @   Push set of Parameters on stack
                    LDR     R0,=CELSIUS_TEMPS1      @   Load pointer to array
                    LDR     R1,=CELSIUS_AV          @   Load pointer to Celsius_AV array
                    MOV     R2,#NUM                 @   Initialize counter NUM=8


                    BL      CONVERSION              @   Call Procedure to do work
    CONVERSION:     STMFD   R13!, {R5-R8,R14}       @   Save used registers and Return address on stack
    NEXT2:          LDRB    R6,[R0],#1              @   Get Celsius_Temps byte
                    MUL     R8,R6,#9                @   Multiply first Celsius_Temps by 9
                    MOV     R5,#0                   @   Counter
    LOOP: 
                    ADD     R5,R5,#1                @   Counter plus 1
                    SUB     R8,#5                   @   Subtract 5 from R8
                    CMP     R8,#0                   @   Compare R8 to zero
                    BPL     LOOP                    @   Go to LOOP if positive or zero
                    MOV     R8,R5                   @   Division by 5 into R8
                    ADD     R8,#32                  @   Add to 32 to complete conversion 
                    STR     R8,[R0],#1              @   Store in (FAHRENHEIT_TEMPS) array
                    MOV     R2,#16                  @   Set counter to 16
                    SUBS    R2,R2,#1                @   Decrement counter
                    BNE     NEXT2                   @   Repeat until 16 elements converted
                    ADD     R13,R13,#12             @   Add 12 to point R13 at parameters pushed on stack
                    LDMFD   R13!, {R0-R2}           @   Pop pushed values off stack into registers R0-R2
    NEXT3:          LDRB    R6,[R0],#1              @   Get Fahrenheit_Temps byte, increment pointer
                    LDRB    R7,[R0],#1              @   Get Next Fahrenheit_Temps byte, increment pointer
                    ADD     R5,R7,R6                @   Add sum in R5
                    ADD     R8,R8,R5                @   Add sum in R8
                    SUBS    R2,R2,#1                @   Decrement element counter
                    BNE     NEXT3                   @   Repeat loop until 16 elements added
                    MOVS    R8,R8,LSR#4             @   Divide by 16 LSB to carry
                    ADC     R8,R8,#0                @   Add contents of carry flag to sum
                                                    @   in R8 to round result up if carry=1
                    STRB    R8,[R1]                 @   Copy result byte to FAHRENHEIT_AV array
                    SUB     R13,R13,#32             @   Add 32 to get back to original position
                    LDMFD   R13!, {R6-R8,R14}       @   Pop pushed values off stack into registers 
                    ADD     R13,R13,#20             @   Add 20 to R13 to put stack pointer back at 
                                                    @   original position (Balance Stack)
                    MOV     PC,R14                  @   Return to mainline program

    .data
    CELSIUS_TEMPS1:     .byte   0x00,0x03,0x06,0x09,0x0C,0x0F,0X12,0X15,0X18,0X1B,0X1E,0X21,0X24,0X27,0X2A,0X2D
    CELSIUS_AV:         .byte   0X00
    FAHRENHEIT_TEMPS:   .byte   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
    FAHRENHEIT_AV:      .byte   0x00    

    STACK:              .rept   256                 @   Reserve 256 bytes for stack and init with 0x00
                        .byte   0x00    
                        .endr   


  .end
```

I have re-worked my code so that the division works, but unless I comment out the Pushing to R13, the stack, I cannot debug the program. I can't push or pop from the stack? When I get to storing to the arrays it will give me data abort in the debugger as well. 
I know the arrays worked and did what they were supposed to in the first part of the assignment. I just don't know how I am not able to put registers and arrays on the stack?

Comment: your stack is word aligned?

Comment: You are popping more than pushing.  Try pushing & popping the same things.  Also, you need to have some code in the main after the call instruction, or else there is no point in returning.

Comment: How to align my stack to byte? I re-worked the program so that the division works well enough and I tried pushing and popping just a number or one register and still getting caught up on not being able to push anything?

Comment: So if I did .align 1 ? Do you think that might work?

Comment: Surely you want it to be (at least) word-aligned?

Comment: SP is 0x27e, which is not aligned at all. You need to align the initial SP value. An '.align 3' directive before the STACK label might work, but your compiler/assembler chain may have a different one. Also, your code is a little too low level. Your environment probably supplies a framework that initializes memory and sets up the stack.